# iTunes Get the language of Current Video

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript, itunes-app

I am using `com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo`distributed notification to get notified whenever player is stooped, played, paused etc. Once I receive this notification I use `ScriptableFramework` to collect video meta data. There are some (https://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/id704994304) which have multiple audio tracks. My requirement is to get the language of current track also to get notification whenever user changes the audio language of the video. When I change audio track if video my app doesn't receive `com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo` notification also when I pause the video iTunes.h doesn't has any property which gives the language of video.

Comment: Can you link to free movie/podcast with multiple audio tracks? I think more users can help you if they don't have to spend $15 for a movie in the first place.

Comment: I dont know if any free movie is available with multiple audio tracks. But [Percy Jackson: Sea of Monsters](https://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/id704994304) is the cheapest one $4.99. I am also using this one for my testing :)